# org.webjars in SpringBoot app

Tags: jquery, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I also have this property defined in my application.properties

```
server.contextPath=/appContext
```

I have this dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

in the template:

```
<script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js}"></script>
```

But I got a 404 accessing to `http://localhost:8080/appContext/webjars/jquery/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js`

and I try to find the resource in Eclipse using `Open Resource....` but I couldn't find it either.

Comment: Why are you including `appContext` in the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<script src="/webjars/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/webjars/jquery/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You may also want to try cdn as follows:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"
        th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working on thymeleaf and webjars, following works for me

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webjars/jquery-ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js}"></script>
```